# How to push json data into XY array for React-vis?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-vis

Looking to start some graphing in react-vis and am wondering what's the best approach for pushing data from a json to state so I can access the state data from graphing. Below is my test json:

```
[
    {
      "day": "1",
      "flights":"58",
      "passengers": "6076"
    },
    {
        "day": "2",
        "flights": "78",
        "passengers": "7089"
    },
    {
        "day": "3",
        "flights": "101",
        "passengers": "9760"
    }
]
```

I essentially want to push "day" and "flights" into the data array to mimic the sample provided by react-vis. Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
//import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import my_data from './data/csvjson.json';
import {XYPlot, XAxis, YAxis, HorizontalGridLines, LineSeries,
   VerticalGridLines, LineMarkSeries} from 'react-vis';
import '../node_modules/react-vis/dist/style.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     data:[]
  }
  }

  //react vis documentation points to data being an object like so:
   //sample data 
   //data:[
   // {x: 0, y: 8},
   // {x: 1, y: 5},
   // {x: 2, y: 4}
  // ]

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <XYPlot width={400} height={300}><XAxis/><YAxis/>
          <HorizontalGridLines />
          <VerticalGridLines />
          <LineMarkSeries data={this.state.data} />
        </XYPlot>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--wouldn't you just `map` the flight data, returning a new object with `{x: flights, y: passengers}` (or whatever you want) for each one? What's the specific issue you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preprocess `my_data` and store it in the state. There should be one function which maps over the `my_data` and return the array with ojects having x and y properties `{x: day, y: flight}`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import my_data from './data/csvjson.json';
import {XYPlot, XAxis, YAxis, HorizontalGridLines, LineSeries,
   VerticalGridLines, LineMarkSeries} from 'react-vis';

const processData = (data) => {
  return data.map(e => ({
    x: e.day,
    y: e.flights
  }));
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: processData(my_data)
    };
  }

  render() {
        return (
      <div>
          <XYPlot width={400} height={300}><XAxis/><YAxis/>
          <HorizontalGridLines />
          <VerticalGridLines />
          <LineMarkSeries data={this.state.data} />
        </XYPlot>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I also did it on stackblitz, you can check the live demo there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-abkc1j

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is simply create a new array with the data you've retrieved from some API. This is most simply done via `.map`. You could run something like this:

`jsonData.map((entry) => ({x: entry.day, y: entry.flights}))`